# How to properly css-grid this alignment solution? (individual row height, but maintaining specific order on min screens)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The code snippet below creates the desired behaviour for my components.
I want each row to have an individual height, both elements in that row to have the same height, and for small screens, only 1 column, and all "A" content should come first, then all "B" content.

It is just that my solution feels wrong to me. I feel like I am missing grid fundamentels on how to achieve this.
To be honest, I expected that giving A `grid-column: 1` and B `grid-column: 2` should have worked, but it did not.

FYI: the inline style height is just for simplification. In reality, I do not know the height.  and the code looks something like this:

```
<Grid>
  {CME puts all A here}
  {CME puts all B here}
</Grid>
```

```css
.A {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.B {
  /* grid-column: 2; */
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  column-gap: 2%;
  row-gap: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="A">A1</div>
  <div class="A" style="height: 150px">A2</div>
  <div class="A" style="height: 50px">A3</div>
  <div class="B" style="height: 200px">B1</div>
  <div class="B">B2</div>
  <div class="B">B3</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of what this is supposed to look like on both large and small screens. There seems to be some confusion about rows and columns here.

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit about which column you want B to go into.

This snippet ensures it's in column 2 in the wide version and in column 1 in the narrow one.

```css
.A {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.B {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  column-gap: 2%;
  row-gap: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .B {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="A">A1</div>
  <div class="A" style="height: 150px">A2</div>
  <div class="A" style="height: 50px">A3</div>
  <div class="B" style="height: 200px">B1</div>
  <div class="B">B2</div>
  <div class="B">B3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, maybe i phrased my question badly. But your snippet is the same as mine - and as soon as I omit the grid-auto-flow: dense, it does not work. Shouldn't there be a more straightforward, simplistic way, with just naming the respective columns? the auto-flow dense feels like the hacky part to me.

Comment: The snippet isn't the same [it is explicit about columns], but the outcome may not be what you want as I may have misinterpreted what your requihrement is. Could you describe what you want to happen on small screens. I'd assumed that you wanted them in one column, but realise now you say one row in your question, is that really right?

Comment: No your assumption is right, I made a blunder there.
Yes the outcome is correct, but only with auto-flow dense. Maybe I am wrong but I assume this is a basic use case for css-grid (both vertical and horizontal alignment) and this could be solved more elegant.

Comment: If all your problem is autoflow  'dense', it can be changed to 'column' and it will also work